# Unable to print the tables side by side(horizontally)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to print the tables side by side using bootstrap like this[image]

but when I try to print preview, I'm getting this [image]
My code is given below. I tried all the possible solutions, but I don't know why I'm unable to print the page that I'm seeing. Please guide me in solving this problem.

```
<style>
.print-wrapper{padding-top:25px;width:768px;margin:0 auto;}.
print .active{font-weight:bold;height:50px;background-color:lightgray;}
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="print-wrapper well well-lg clearfix">
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="col-md-12 border-design">
<table align="left" border="1" bordercolor="#CCC" class="table table-condensed print">
<tbody> 
<tr class="active">
<td style="text-align:center">#</td>
<td>Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item 1</td>
<td></td>
</tr>           
<tr>
<td>Item 2</td>
<td></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>Item 3</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item 4</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item 5</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>    
<p style="text-align:justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut felis non sem vulputate congue. Integer enim mauris, malesuada eu posuere non, semper a ex. Duis at urna id urna egestas ultricies sit amet nec eros. Maecenas in risus ex. Curabitur iaculis quam arcu, vitae pretium massa lacinia vel. Aenean vel rutrum odio. Nulla purus ante, eleifend ut congue non, ornare at nisi. Sed viverra maximus sapien, non condimentum augue blandit finibus. </p>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="col-md-12 border-design">
<table align="left" border="1" bordercolor="#CCC" class="table table-condensed print">
<tbody> 
<tr class="active">
<td  colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Customer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%">Name</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>           
<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>DOB</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile No</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table align="left" border="1" bordercolor="#CCC" class="table table-condensed print">
<tbody> 
<tr class="active">
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Customer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%">Name</td>
<td></td>
</tr>           
<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>DOB</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile No</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        table 1 html
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        table 2 html
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        text html
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        table 3 html
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there are two separate rows.  Each row has a total of 12 columns by default.

Therefore you have table 1 take up 6/12 columns, and table 2 take up the other 6/12 columns.  If the sum of the columns of table 1 + table 2 > 12, then table 2 will get moved to the second row.

The second row is exactly the same as the first, the only difference being the content of the divs.

Also note, since you are using col-md, any display smaller than md will have each table take up the full 12 columns.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Now my web page and print preview pages are same, but not as I expected. After using this, now the table in my web page is showing one by one like the print preview image I attached in my question, but the tables are half of the page size

Comment: Are you still using .print-wrapper?  If all you want is what's shown in your example, you shouldn't need any other css then what I've written above.

Comment: Also, you can use container or container-fluid depending on how wide you want your margins.

Comment: I tried removing all my css and added only the code that you suggested but still I'm getting the same thing